# Laravel view output displays on top of page instead of displaying in the page container

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-4

I have been playing around with Laravel for the past 2 days and have made a bit of progress.

There are some issues that I still have not been able to resolve. One of them is that :-

my output for :-

```
    foreach($data as $msg){
        echo $msg;
    }
```

in my view gets displayed on top of page.

I have worked on the html and css with twitter bootstrap and have made the layout for my website. I just wanted to see how controllers, models and view work in Laravel, and wanted to echo a message in the view which is generated in the model.

But the problem now is that it is not displaying at the correct position.

Comment: Can you post your `view` blade html, are you using a master view to inherit HTML from?

Comment: ummm, i just copy pasted my html to the view called homepage.php - changed the header so that css and js, bootstrap can be accessed from the public directory.

Comment: and I am not using blade as of now

Comment: Create a view in the `views` folder called `homepage.blade.php`. Then in your controller, you can tell it which view to use.

Comment: but wudn't tat require me to use blade template syntax..?

Comment: Yes - and also looks nicer (my preference!) to the `php` syntax. But also allows you to extend layouts, `@extends('layout')` so that you don't have to copy the header, footer, container into every single template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your `foreach` code is in your controller.  Anything there is processed first, then your view is displayed.

I suspect what you really want is to pass that data *into* your view and display it there.  So, your controller method should look something like:

```
public function myMethod() {
    $data = ....
    return View::make('myview', compact('data'));
}
```

And then you can add the PHP block to your view:

```
<?php foreach($data as $msg) {
    echo $msg;
} ?>
```

Or switch to blade templates and do something like

```
@foreach($data as $msg)
<p>
    {{{ $msg }}}
</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: ya this helped - actually, the message was being displayed from model as I had echoed the message instead of returning